# JavaScript pushState does not work on browser going back

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate

The concerning site-url is *example.com/news/*. The page that is loaded via this url contains some checkboxes and a button. I use an object *filter* with some keys like *checkbox1*, *checkbox2*, etc. and if the checkboxes are checked the keys get a *true*-value, if they are unchecked the keys get a *false*-value.

In the end, there is a var *overwriteURL*, which contains let's say the value "general-seniors-youth".

Now when the button is clicked, I want the script to load a page into a container and change the url to *example.com/news/general-seniors-youth/* without loading a new site.
I achieve this by the following code:

```
if(overwriteURL !== "" ) {
   history.pushState({ test: "test" }, null, "/news/" + overwriteURL + "/");
}
```

That works fine.
As the documentation of Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) says in English:
If I navigate to google.com (for example) after the script ran and then use the back-button of my browser, the URL-bar should actually contain the changed URL, so *example.com/news/general-seniors-youth/*. But it does contain the orginal URL before the pushState, so *example.com/news/*.
But when I don't navigate to *google.com* but use the back-button as often as I want and then the forward-button till it reaches the latest history-entry, then the rigth (changed) URLis displayed in the URL-bar.

Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know how, but I found a solution.

I figured that, the problem seems to be depending on the content of the var *overwriteURL*. On the real site, the var sometimes consists of a mixture of characters and numbers and the *--* to seperate the values (for example: *-general--seniors--u19--u16--press-*).

When I experimented with the content of the var *overwriteURL*, sometimes there was no problem. So finally I replaced the *--* by */* and now it works perfectly. The new var *overwriteURL* for example looks like *general/seniors/u19/u16/press/*.

So, as a conclusion, it seems as if there is a problem with to many *-* in the URL.

Case closed!